# Agrupar resultados de consulta SQL por un campo

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Tengo una tabla tal que así:

```
|  ID  |  id_foreign  | cosa  |
-------------------------------
|  1   |      1       | cosa1 |
|  2   |      1       | cosa2 |
|  3   |      2       | cosa1 |
|  4   |      3       | cosa1 |
|  5   |      4       | cosa1 |
|  6   |      4       | cosa2 |
|  7   |      4       | cosa3 |
|  8   |      4       | cosa4 |
-------------------------------
```

Lo que quiero es
Mostrar con php y html una tabla donde me salga por ejemplo:

```
|   id_foreign  |   cosas    |
------------------------------
|      1        |   · cosa1  |
|               |   · cosa2  |
------------------------------
|      2        |   · cosa1  |
------------------------------
|      3        |   · cosa1  |
------------------------------
|      4        |   · cosa1  |
|               |   · cosa2  |
|               |   · cosa3  |
|               |   · cosa4  |
------------------------------
```

Como debería hacer la consula para obtener ese resultado?

O más bien se tiene que hacer con sql o se puede hacer con php?

Gracias

Comment: Espero que mi respuesta soluciona tu problema, he implementado justo lo que pides.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

prueba esto:

```
SELECT id_foreign,group_concat(concat(' . ',cosa) separator '<br>') as cosas    
from table
group by id_foreign
```

Comment: Al hacer la consulta de esa manera en el phpmyadmin funciona correctamente, pero al hacerlo desde el php no me la hace. me dice que undefined column `cosa`

Comment: la columna que debes usar es cosas, podrías agregar antes de calificar como mala la respuesta como estas intentando hacerlo desde php.

Comment: Al final el undefined era cosa de mi codigo, ya está solucionado gracias por tu respuesta.

Answer (score 1):

No sé si usas `PDO`, `mysqli`, etc, de modo que lo haré código independiente:

```
<?php
/* Simulo una variable con tu contenido para obtener registros de ella
  basta con un SELECT * FROM tabla , no hay necesidad de usar GROUP BY */
$registros = [
  [ 'ID' => 1, 'id_foreign' => 1, 'cosa' => 'cosa1' ],
  [ 'ID' => 2, 'id_foreign' => 1, 'cosa' => 'cosa2' ],
  [ 'ID' => 3, 'id_foreign' => 2, 'cosa' => 'cosa1' ],
  [ 'ID' => 4, 'id_foreign' => 3, 'cosa' => 'cosa1' ],
  [ 'ID' => 5, 'id_foreign' => 4, 'cosa' => 'cosa1' ],
  [ 'ID' => 6, 'id_foreign' => 4, 'cosa' => 'cosa2' ],
  [ 'ID' => 7, 'id_foreign' => 4, 'cosa' => 'cosa3' ],
  [ 'ID' => 8, 'id_foreign' => 4, 'cosa' => 'cosa4' ],
];

$datos = [];
/* Creamos una matriz con índice 'id_foreign' con elementos variables */
foreach ($registros as $registro) {
  $datos[$registro['id_foreign']][] = $registro;
}
?><table border="1">
<tr><th>id_foreign</th><th>cosa</th></tr>
<?php
/* Obtenemos una a una cada una de las id_foreign */
foreach ($datos as $id_foreign => $fila) {
  /* Ahora, por cada elemento que tenga cada id_foreign creamos una fila */
  foreach ($fila as $indice => $elemento) {
?>  <tr>
<?php
    /* Si es el primer elemento deberemos crear la celda que muestra el id_foreign y decirle el alto (la cantidad de elementos que contiene) */
    if ($indice === 0) {
?>    <td rowspan="<?= count($fila) ?>"><?= htmlentities($id_foreign) ?></td>
<?php
    }
?>    <td><?= htmlentities($elemento['cosa']) ?></td>
  </tr>
<?php
  }
} 
?>
</table>
```

Answer (score -1):

si necesitas agrupar campos, creo que debes mirar la clausula GROUP BY
Ejemplo
http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp

Comment: Cuando hago group by simplemente me sale uno de los campos con el mismo foreign key es decir si par el foreign key 1 tengo dos registros, solo sale uno.

Comment: Te recomendaria que agregaras un ejemplo, para que sea mas claro para el usuario que pregunta